# How to throw custom error in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) or die(mysql_error())
```

In this code the `mysql_error` will be displayed if `mysql_fetch_array` fails. Is there any way to throw that `mysql_error` to reload a page instead.

P.S.: I know `mysql` has been depreciated. Its an old project so please don't suggest in your answers to use `mysqli` and `PDO`. I am well aware of it. Please tell me the way to throw reload page as error.

Comment: can you please be more clear about what you want to do

Comment: if(whatever) {throw new Exception();}

Comment: You want to reload the page if the query has an error in it? But wouldn't you get the same problem and therefor having an infinite loop?

Comment: No i have different scnario here

Comment: Function results (bool) false if there's no (more) rows to fetch - this expression dies every time (unless you know rows number and prevent it). "Error false" is returned with `$result` assign.

Answer (score 0):

You could use try catch for exception handling in PHP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

```
try
    {
     // do something that can go wrong
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
     throw new Exception( 'Something wrong', 0, $e);
    }
```

OR

```
 try 
    {
       // do something that can go wrong
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof CustomException)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else if ($e instanceof OtherException)
        {
           // do something
        }
        else
        {
           // do something
        }
    }
```

Or

```
try 
{

}
catch (CustomException $e)
{

}
catch (OtherException $e)
{

}
catch (Exception $e)
{

}
```